# NSTextlist issue in Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I wrote the following code to get list in a nstextview. The issue is, in first line number (1) is appearing correctly and after entering some data and press enter second line number (2)  should automatically appear. but it isn't. Any help is appreciated

```
@IBAction func numberList(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.editorView.textStorage?.beginEditing()
    var paragraph : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    var textList : NSTextList  = NSTextList(markerFormat: "{decimal}.", options: 0)
    paragraph.textLists = [textList]

    var attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\t \(textList.markerForItemNumber(1)) \t", attributes: [paragraph : NSParagraphStyleAttributeName])

    self.editorView.textStorage?.appendAttributedString(attributedString)
    self.editorView.textStorage?.endEditing()
}
```

Comment: You paragraph style attribute dict is backwards: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName should be the ***key***.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. With the change jtbandes mentions, everything seems to work fine here. Pressing Enter once yields a new line with a marker. Pressing Enter twice in succession yields a new empty line.

Comment: Thankyou jtbandes. It is working now.